# applescript & numbers error setting variable to value of empty cell in numbers

Tags: numbers, applescript

never worked with applescript and am only hobbiest with coding

```
tell application "Numbers"
    tell front document to tell sheet 1 to tell table 1
    set col to 3
    repeat
        set ABCD to value of cell {row 2, column col}
        if value of cell {row foundRow, column col} is missing value then display dialog "yay"
        exit repeat
        set col to col + 1
    end repeat
end tell
```

I tore apart the code and simplified it for you but no matter how i dice it up trying to pull the value of cell that is empty which that cell is gives me an error, I can't even pull the value to test it against... missing value... so I'm at a loss any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Numbers so I can't test this code, but there are a few changes I would make to it from what I'm seeing. It appears you are trying to find a blank column? You didn't make that very clear in your question. If so, I would try something like this. (Again, this is untested)

```
set foundBlank to false
set lastColumnToCheck to 30

tell application "Numbers"
    tell table 1 of sheet 1 of front document

    repeat with col from 3 to lastColumnToCheck
        set ABCD to value of cell {row 2, column col}
        if ABCD = "" then
            set foundBlank to true
            exit repeat
        end if
    end repeat
end tell

if foundBlank then
    display dialog "Yay!"
else
    display dialog "Boo!"
end if
```